# How do I check the status of my Snowflake connection in Python?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm using python to query data from snowflake. First I create a connector using the following code -

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
      user = myusername,
      pass = mypassword,
      account = accountname

)
```

when I run `con`, I get `<snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection at 0x240a2e8b8b0>`. However even after I run `con.close()`, when I run `con` I still get `<snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection at 0x240a2e8b8b0>`, even though the connection is closed.

How do I check the status of `con` to determine if it is open or closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection at 0x240a2e8b8b0>` is the default **repr** which is printing you Connection, as the name of the object `snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection` and the memory reference (which allows telling two same typed objects part).

So given your object is a Connection, it's not going to become invalid from a python object level, because the underlying connection is closed, or had exceptions etc etc.

The [Connection](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#object-connection) object description does not mention any "status" properties.

Generally the status is not needed. You should be able to close it many time with no side effect, if that is a concern. And if you have not used it for a while and it has timed-out, when you use the connection, it should throw an error, which you handle and re-try, and if the error is a type the indicates "the connection is not valid" you make a new connection first.

Comment: I'd like to determine if the connection has timed out without making a call. Is this possible?

Comment: the neat thing is to check the status of "a thing" and to tell your process, new event things has changed, "some code" has to make a timer and later do the check and then tell you. Somewhere, somehow, something has to do the work to know the state has changed. Which is to say, be the code you wished was already there. But I also get your point that if there was already code that just did what you need it would be nice not to have to duplicate it's code, and possible get it wrong.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but there's a `connection.is_closed()` method in the Snowflake python connector now. I don't know if it previously existed.